# How this series is produced?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> All derivatives can be expressed exactly in terms of infinite series
>   of forward, backward, or central-differences. For example
>   $$\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{h^2} ( \delta_x^2 U - \frac{1}{12} \delta_x^4 U + \frac{1}{90} \delta_x^6 U + \cdots ) \tag{$*$}$$ where the subscript $x$ denotes differencing in the
>   $x$-direction and the central-differences are defined by $$\delta_x U_{i,\,j} = U_{i+\frac{1}{2},\,j}-U_{i-\frac{1}{2},\,j}$$ and 
>   $$\delta_x^2 U_{i,\,j} = \delta_x(\delta_x U_{i,\,j})=U_{i+1,\,j}-2U_{i,\,j}+U_{i-1,\,j}, \quad \text{etc.}$$

---

In the quote above, which is from [a book](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/numerical-solution-of-partial-differential-equations-9780198596509?cc=gb&lang=en&), it has been said that differential equations can be written as infinite series using finite-differences. As you can see in the ($*$) equation, the author has achieved the desired issue using the central-differences. The more I struggle to understand how the author has achieved to the aforementioned series, the less I progress! 
It is worth mentioning that the book hasn't have explained about the way any more.
What I've get so far is that the central-differences of second order are written for three nominal.

[Second Order Central Differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rHfY.jpg)

But the weird thing is that the denominator of the third expression is 180, while by using the central-differences it would be 90 in the very text of the book.
Please, someone enlighten me regarding the ($*$) series (how is that produced?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is an informal description, but it should give you an idea how one discover such a formula.

Let $X$ be a space of test functions on $\mathbb{R}$ which are smooth and sufficiently regular that following descriptions make sense. On $X$, define
an operator $D$ and a family of operators $T_a$, one for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$ as follows:

- For any $\phi \in X, x, a \in \mathbb{R}$,
  $$(D\phi)(x) = \frac{d\phi}{dx}(x)\quad\text{ and }\quad (T_a\phi)(x) = \phi(x+a)$$

i.e. $D$ is the operator for taking derivative and $T_a$ is the operator to translate the function for an amount $-a$. If we apply Taylor series expansion
to $T_a\phi$, we find

$$(T_a\phi)(x) = \phi(x+a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!} \frac{d^n\phi(x)}{dx^n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!} (D^n\phi)(x)$$
So formally, we have

$$T_a = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}D^n = e^{aD}$$

In terms of $T_a$, the central difference operator $\delta_x$ is simply $T_{\frac12} - T_{-\frac12}$. This leads to

$$\delta_x = e^{\frac{D}{2}} - e^{-\frac{D}{2}} = 2\sinh\left(\frac{D}{2}\right)
\quad\implies\quad  D^2 = \left(2\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{\delta_x}{2}\right)\right)^2\tag{*1}$$

If you throw the function $(2\sinh^{-1}(t/2))^2$ to an CAS and expand it as a power series of $t$,
you will get

$$(2\sinh^{-1}(t/2))^2 =
t^2 - \frac{t^4}{12} + \frac{t^6}{90} - \frac{t^8}{560} + \frac{t^{10}}{3150} - \cdots$$

Substitute this expansion into RHS of $(*1)$ and apply suitable scaling  (because $h \ne 1$), you
obtain the mysterious representation of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ as a power series of $\delta_x^2$.

About the second half of your question, I have no idea what are 
those expressions after the line
`the central-differences of second order are written for three nominal`
in your question.
The coefficients for the even-order
[higher-order differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) I know are all binomial coefficients and forming a row of Pascal's triangle.